# Using same directory for storing all uploaded images on a Wordpress network

Tags: uploads, multisite

I currently use a Wordpress network in order to run a number of sites, which all use the same template, plugins and images. As posts appear on a multiple sites, it makes sense to only upload images to one location (and have one copy of an image), rather than multiple ones.

Could I perhaps achieve this by creating a custom rewrite? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

**Background information**

I am using WPThree Broadcast to 'broadcast' an image over multiple sites, and therefore also copy the images into their respective image libraries. I don't want the server to get cluttered with ten copies of the same image so instead am checking to see if the image is already in a site's `wp_posts` table, and then if not copying the `post` and `post_meta` data into that site's tables.

However, I do *not* wish to copy the actual image into a new upload folder, as the default WP is configured to do (e.g. into `/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/`), so instead I want all images to be uploaded to `/wp-content/uploads/`, the default upload folder for a standard WP installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pretty simple add some actions to archive this.

```
function wpse_16722_main_uploads() {
    switch_to_blog(1);
}
add_action('load-media-new.php', 'wpse_16722_main_uploads');
add_action('load-media-upload.php', 'wpse_16722_main_uploads');
add_action('load-media.php', 'wpse_16722_main_uploads');
add_action('load-upload.php', 'wpse_16722_main_uploads');
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_16722_main_uploads');
```

This will change the current sub-blog to user your main-site with the help of [switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and of course you want the main side by the id 1.

You can also add a function to rewrite the upload folder to only /uploads without the subdirs:

```
function wpse_16722_upload_dir( $args ) {
    $newdir = '/';

    $args['path']    = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['path'] ); //remove default subdir
    $args['url']     = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['url'] );      
    $args['subdir']  = $newdir;
    $args['path']   .= $newdir; 
    $args['url']    .= $newdir; 

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_16722_upload_dir' );
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work with WP 3.5 - the new media manager is written in `backbone.js` so switching doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it does, switch_to_blog has nothing with backbone or jQuery to do. It simply change the upload path and media-library to main-site.

Comment: Have you really tried this yet?

Comment: I've ended up using just the second part of your answer to rewrite the upload folder to use `/uploads`, which doesn't require using `switch_to_blog(1)` which is where I was previously having issues. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the post ["How to Change the Default Media Upload Location in WordPress 3.5"](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-default-media-upload-location-in-wordpress-3-5/) by Editorial Staff, they show how to change the upload dir in `wp-config.php` :

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this constant don't work in Multisite, as asked by the OP :/